# asp-route-* attribute where is the doc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

where could we read more details about the "asp-route-*" razor attribute?

I read from [here the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-route-value) but is does not specify the "value" format...

say I have

```
@model Speaker
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <a asp-controller="Speaker"
       asp-action="Detail"
       asp-route-speakerid="@Model.SpeakerId">SpeakerId: @Model.SpeakerId</a>
<body>
</html>
```

and the action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int speakerId)
```

should I use in razor `asp-route-speakerId` or maybe `asp-route-speaker-id` or `asp-route-speakerid`?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/04ce6cae44fb0cb11470c21769d41e3f8088e8aa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs#L136   speakerid or speakerId or asp-route-SPEAKERID="11" worked

Comment: @TinyWang probably worked, but not documented to users

Comment: just test my ourselives. ... yes, we can only do it when the document is not so complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a asp-controller="Speaker"
       asp-action="Detail"
       asp-route-speakerid="@Model.SpeakerId">SpeakerId: @Model.SpeakerId
</a>
```

Will generate like this in html:

```
<a href="/Speaker/Detail?speakerid=xxxx">xxxxx</a>
```

Because `Name` matching is not case-sensitive. So you can even write like this (refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)):

```
<a asp-controller="Speaker"
           asp-action="Detail"
           asp-route-SPEAKERID="@Model.SpeakerId">SpeakerId: @Model.SpeakerId
    </a>

public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int speakerId)
```

It can still work well. But you can't write like `asp-route-speaker-id`,Because it does not match `speakerId` in your controller.

Comment: the article in the linked document does not specify the html attribute format to use

Comment: yes, But it shows `Name` matching is not case-sensitive when bind model from route.

Comment: there are languages that transform "xxx-yzz" values in "xxxYzz", the "HTML attribute" format is neither directly or indirectly specified, and to link the model binding and the html attribute format is not really evident.

Comment: I can get your point. Actually, This question is similar with  can I use `speakerId` to bind `/Speaker/Detail?speaker-id=xxxx` in route, `Model Binding` use `property name` to bind data. In Microsoft document, I don't find any word mention about  `transform "xxx-yzz" values in "xxxYzz"`, I tried it myself and couldn't bind successfully. So in my opinion, `xxx-yzz` to  `xxxYzz` can not work in Model Binding.